# Share a variable between functions in implementation of a interface

Tags: java, interface, field

Consider an interface and its implementation,

```
interface A {
    int a;
    default void add() {
        a = a+10;
    }
    public void sub();
}

class X implements A {
    public sub() {
        a = a-5;
    }
}
```

I have to use the variable `a` in `sub()` function of class `X`. How can I do?

Comment: It might not seem like it, but `a` is a constant. You can't reassign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables declared inside interface are implicitly public static final variables(constants).

From the Java interface design FAQ by Philip Shaw:

Interface variables are static because Java interfaces cannot be instantiated in their own right; the value of the variable must be assigned in a static context in which no instance exists. The final modifier ensures the value assigned to the interface variable is a true constant that cannot be re-assigned by program code.

Since interface doesn't have a direct object, the only way to access them is by using a class/interface and hence that is why if interface variable exists, it should be static otherwise it wont be accessible at all to outside world. Now since it is static, it can hold only one value and any classes that implements it can change it and hence it will be all mess.

Hence if at all there is an interface variable, it will be implicitly static, final and obviously public!!!

Comment: Can you include the link?

Comment: Reply very well explains, it's not possible to modify interface variables since they are constants. Guess this should have been a comment rather than an answer, as this post does not help cause for question.

Answer (score 2):

The field `a` in the interface `A` always `final` and `static` and it isn't supposed to be modified in any way including reassigning it in an instance method.

Interfaces don't have the state. Abstract classes may.

```
abstract class A {
    protected int a;

    public void add() {
        a += 10;
    }
    public abstract void sub();
}

final class X extends A {
    public void sub() {
        a -= 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an abstract class instead of an interface. That way the variable can be modified by the extending class.

```java
abstract class A{
    int a=10;
    void add(){
        a=a+10;
    }
    public abstract void sub();
}
class X extends A{
    public void sub(){
        a=a-5;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can use abstract class.
Since in interface variables declared are by default final.

[Code with Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URB0Z.png)

[Code with Abstract Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DObNr.png)